# Apache Camel call https rest service doesn't work through proxy

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, http-proxy

When i want to call Rest service from Apache camel I always get `com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixTimeoutException: null`
I set proxy in the vm and also in intellj but no one worked.
I also set proxy for apache Camel that [mentioned in Camel Site](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http-component.html):

```
 context.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "172.168.18.9");
 context.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort" "8080");
```

but still not worked.
When i try to call the service with Post Man it connect successfully.

Comment: Could you add the whole HTTP client configuration and call steps?

Comment: After I add &proxyAuthHost=****&proxyAuthPort=****&proxyAuthScheme=http to the http4s endpoint then exception change to Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target